# Simple C program won't run in MSVS, runs fine in Linux GCC

Tags: c, exception, fgets

Simple C program won't run in MSVS, runs fine in Linux GCC

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h> //printf, scanf, fopen
#include <string.h> //strcpy, strlen
#include <math.h> // PI, E, trig functions
#include <ctype.h> //isalpha, tolower
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        FILE *fptr;
        fptr = fopen("myText.txt", "r");
        if (fptr == NULL) {
                puts("could not open file");
                return 1;
                }

        char string[60];
        int line = 0;

        while (fgets(string, 60, fptr) != NULL) {
                printf("line %d %s\n", line++, string);

        }

        fclose(fptr);
        return 0;
}
```

I acknowledge (1) there are unused include statements and (2) I don't use argc or argv. However these are not the problem.

When I run this code in MS Visual Studio, at the fgets line I get:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDC2C5168D (ntdll.dll) in Try4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000039.

But when I copy & paste into WSL and run it under GCC it works fine. I thought adding

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

would stop VS from complaining, but apparently not. Sorry - I'm still learning  and don't know what the unhandled exception message is trying to tell me, or why the NO_WARNINGS macro doesn't help

Comment: You misunderstand what `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` does. It prevents MSVC compiler from complaining about "unsafe" functions. It will not have any effect on wrong usage and such crashes.

Comment: You should run the program in the debugger and see where the problem occurs. Then check the variables' content for unexpected values.

Comment: It works fine on my Visual Studio 2022 and your code looks more or less correct to me. Are you sure the code you show is the code you compile and run? What dis the debugger tell you?